# Report changes to a custom delegate object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

So I'm trying to implement a modal view for adding items to a table view..

In the tutorial I'm following, I see

```
RecipeAddViewController *addController = [[RecipeAddViewController alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"RecipeAddView" bundle:nil];

addController.delegate = self;
```

I assume the .delegate = self is so that that current controller knows about what happens in the modal view, is that correct? If so, how do implement it in my code since I don't have the property called delegate.

Do I need to create a property and synthesize it in my view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the required RecipeAddViewDelegate methods and you can implement the optional ones. See UITableView, -Controller and -Delegate for examples.